# I want to get some data from source code using php

Tags: php

I want to get some data from source code using php.I read html source code with

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents('www.site.com');
?>
<textarea style="width:800px;height:600px"><?php echo $source;?></textarea>
```

I got all html code.
In source code it like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
rangeSelector: {
                    inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3d'
                    },
series: [{
                    name: 'Rate',
                    data: [
[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,10,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,11,30,0),973]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,12,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,13,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,14,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,15,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,10,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,11,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,12,30,0),972]
],
</script>
```

and other html tag

I want only data [Date.UTC(2013,9,2,10,30,0),972] as an array

Comment: So you are getting HTML, than want to extract JS code array? What have you tried?

Comment: So the correct title is "I want to get some data from JavaScript source code using php", right? It is very possible, but you need to do some string parsing staff. It's too long to explain it here.

Comment: I am getting HTML, and then I am trying to get [Date.UTC(2013,9,2,10,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,11,30,0),973]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,12,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,13,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,14,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,15,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,10,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,11,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,12,30,0),972] List from source code as array or variable

Answer (score -1):

By avoiding performance , it can be useful

```php
<?php

$s = "<script type='text/javascript'>
rangeSelector: {
                    inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3d'
                    },
series: [{
                    name: 'Rate',
                    data: [
[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,10,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,11,30,0),973]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,12,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,13,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,14,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,2,15,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,10,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,11,30,0),972]
,[Date.UTC(2013,9,3,12,30,0),972]
],
</script>";


$arr = array();
while (strpos($s,"Date.UTC("))
{
    $i = strpos($s,"Date.UTC")+8;
    $val = substr($s,$i);
    $val = substr($val,0,strpos($val,"]"));
    $arr[] = $val;
    $s = substr($s,$i);
}

var_dump($arr);

?>
```

Result:

```html
array (size=9)
  0 => string '(2013,9,2,10,30,0),972' (length=22)
  1 => string '(2013,9,2,11,30,0),973' (length=22)
  2 => string '(2013,9,2,12,30,0),972' (length=22)
  3 => string '(2013,9,2,13,30,0),972' (length=22)
  4 => string '(2013,9,2,14,30,0),972' (length=22)
  5 => string '(2013,9,2,15,30,0),972' (length=22)
  6 => string '(2013,9,3,10,30,0),972' (length=22)
  7 => string '(2013,9,3,11,30,0),972' (length=22)
  8 => string '(2013,9,3,12,30,0),972' (length=22)
```